# Copying all firmware files from GitHub repository kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware to /lib/firmware

Tags: drivers, kernel, git, firmware

I copied the whole content of https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git to the /lib/firmware folder of my system.

I do not face any issues and it fixed the missing firmware message, but I'm not sure if copying all files this way could cause me any trouble.

Could copying all firmware files with - `sudo cp -r /home/username/linux-firmware/. /lib/firmware/.` cause me any trouble?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

As files are manually installed, those wont be upgraded by standard update process.

You should try to install the `linux-firmware` package with the 'classic' method. In your case, you'll have to add an option for overwriting manually installed files.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite" install linux-firmware
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.